# Drill Down into JSON Object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out the best way to take a json object which I'm storing as a scope, and filter/query it to display specific data from within it.

For example:

```
$scope.myBook = {"bookName": "Whatever",
    "pages": [
        {"pageid": 1, "pageBody": "html content for the page", "pageTitle": "Page 1"},
        {"pageid": 2, "pageBody": "html content for the page", "pageTitle": "Page 2"},
        {"pageid": 3, "pageBody": "html content for the page", "pageTitle": "Page 3"},
    ]
}
```

How would I go about grabbing the object for pageid:2  ?

Comment: You mean grabbing the `pageBody` for `pageid: 2` ?

Comment: Use `for()` to find the necessary page, then use `foundPage.pageBody`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

template:

```
<div ng-repeat="page in myBook.pages | filter:pageMatch(pageid)">
    {{ page.pageBody }}
</div>
```

scope:

```
$scope.pageMatch = function(pageid) {
    return function(page) {
        return page.pageid === pageid;
    };
};
```

Set `pageid` to needed value in `filter:pageMatch(pageid)` to display necessary page content.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPage (id) {
    angular.forEach($scope.myBook.pages, function (page, pageIndex) {
        if (page.pageId == id) {
            console.log("Do something here.");
            return page;
        }
    });
}
```

Otherwise . . .

```
$scope.myBook.pages[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up asking the AngularJS IRC - And one of the guys put this plunker together with exactly what I was looking for.

[Plnkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7MT8hVDssf3CG1GfKrJW?p=preview)

Props to https://github.com/robwormald for the answer.

```
/* See PLNKR Link Above for the answer */
```